# How change focus in reused table view cell with nested collection view in tvOS?

Tags: swift, tvos

I have table view with nested collection view(horizontal scrolling) into table view cell. Something like that:

```
-table view: 
  - section
   - cell: 
    - collection view
```

On starting screen I have 3 sections with 1 cell in each section. When I try to reuse 1 section with cell, **indexPath** for focused item don't change.

For example, if I select 1 section 1 cell and focused **12th** item in collection view, then I scroll down table view in this manner I change focused item and switch to another section of table view. So I reuse cell and see the same focused **indexPath** (**12 row**). So collection view scrolles to this item.

I tried to reset **preferredFocusEnvironments** in

> override func prepareForReuse()

but it had no result. And when I set to false `collectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = false` it didn't help me to solve the  problem. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that problem was in **contentOffset in collectionView**. When I reused tableViewCell I didn't reset offset in collectionView. So I saved all offset for each collectionView in tableViewCell and set this value by key to collectionView. Something like this(in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`):

```
return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(cellClass: HomeTableViewCell.self, for: indexPath).adjust {

    if let id = $0.feedID {
      contentOffsets[id] = $0.collectionView.contentOffset
    }
    $0.preprareForDisplay(feed: feeds[indexPath.section)
    $0.collectionView.contentOffset = contentOffsets[feeds[indexPath.section].origin.id] ?? .zero
  }
```

So after that focus work correct.